# Understanding train_test_split's documentation

Tags: python, scikit-learn, train-test-split

My question is regarding Python's sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split method (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html), to be more precise: its return type.

How do I know what exactly is returned reading this documentation?
(it just says "splitting: list, length=2 * len(arrays), List containing train-test split of inputs.")

Without looking at the examples below I would not have known that it makes sense to call it like X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(...). How would I have known that?

Furthermore I was quite surprised that after inserting a data frame the result is not a data frame any longer and the column names are gone.

Do you also have general advice on how to read Python documentations?

Comment: I mean, the examples are there to illuminate usages like that - and they are part of the documentation. I'd say _Python_ documentation is excellent, other libraries such as this might not be stellar.

Comment: You can alternatively look at the source code here : https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/main/sklearn/model_selection/_split.py#L2553 . You're supposed to look at the example to understand how it work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the function is limited to the examples. It allows an arbitrary number of *indexables* and returns "2 x number of indexables" as can be seen:

> Returns: splittinglist, length=2 * len(arrays)

So, your output can also be an arbitrary number of elements e.g.

`a,b,c,d,e,f = train_test_split(X,y,z)`

also runs successfully. Regarding your other point, scikit-learn uses Numpy for speeding up computations as pandas is quite slow. However, I agree that documentation would be better mentioning the return type